# Using Python to set up ADwin Gold 2 for experimental data gathering and processing

Tags: python

I've recently joined a research group and I'm trying to  figure out how to program in Python to set up an ADwin Gold II to speed up data gathering and processing the results. I'm very rusty with coding haven't done any in a year or so, and finding the docs on ADwin very hard to follow.

If anybody could explain how to used the python ADwin commands from the official python addon, or show me to any material that may be useful. This would be  enormously appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to find, but on the installation folder, in the software folder, you can find a python Manual. There was no mention of this anywhere in the manual I stumbled across it by pure chance.

Any other poor soul out there, may this be an aid in your suffering.